# Groupoid embedding into a group

Tags: group-theory, groupoids

A necessary condition for a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) $(G,∗)$ to embed into a group is that for all $a,b\in G$ then $a ∗ a^{-1}=b∗b^{−1}$.

**Question:** Is this necessary condition also sufficient?

This question came to my mind after reading [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/428405/34538) 2 days before.

Comment: Use `$\in$` for $\in$.

Comment: What do you mean by $a*a^{-1} = b*b^{-1}$? If you take any morphisms $a, b$ in $G$ then they might have different domain/codomain.

Comment: @Jakobian: so equality implies that the domain/codomain is the same.

Comment: Then there can be only one object in this groupoid so the question is trivial.

Comment: @Jakobian: I agree. I just wanted to make sure that I do not miss something, because I am not that familiar with groupoid.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I missed the bit where you just asked for embed! I came here from your other question, where you wanted that it embedded with extra conditions. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would say so. Let's say a group is a one-object categorical groupoid. Under the equivalence of definitions described in the Wikipedia article an algebraic groupoid with the property $a\ast a^{-1}=b\ast b^{-1}$ for all $a,b$ becomes a one-object groupoid, hence a group.

Comment: Let $S$ be a subset of a group $(G,*)$. Then $(S,*)$ could be a groupoid without being a group.

Comment: Ok. But will it be a groupoid with the property in your post / in my answer? I don’t think so